# JSON Parsing using Encodable class

Tags: json, swift, codable

I am trying to parse long response data :

below is the code structure

```
struct VizLog_UserProfile: Codable {
    let data: UserProfileData
    let app: App
}
struct UserProfileData: Codable {
    let roles: [String]
    let users: UserDetails
    let member: ProfileMember

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case roles
        case users
        case member
    }
}
struct UserDetails: Codable {
    let user_id: String
    let auth_id: String
    let unit_id: String
    let company_id: String
    let visitor_id: String
    let session_token: String

    let gender: String
    let visitor_type: String
    let email: String
    let first_name: String
    let last_name: String
    let mobile: String
    let avatar: String
    var complex: Complex? = nil

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case user_id
        case auth_id
        case unit_id
        case company_id
        case visitor_id
        case session_token
        case gender
        case visitor_type
        case email
        case first_name
        case last_name
        case mobile
        case avatar
        case complex = "complex"
    }

    enum Complex_CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case company_id
        case unit_id
        case complex_name
        case setup_steps
        case complex_type
        case access_type
        case pass_type
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        user_id = getValUserDetails(key: .user_id, decoder: decoder, container: container)
        auth_id = getValUserDetails(key: .auth_id, decoder: decoder, container: container)
        unit_id = getValUserDetails(key: .unit_id, decoder: decoder, container: container)
        company_id = getValUserDetails(key: .company_id, decoder: decoder, container: container)
        visitor_id = getValUserDetails(key: .visitor_id, decoder: decoder, container: container)
        session_token = getValUserDetails(key: .session_token, decoder: decoder, container: container)
        gender = getValUserDetails(key: .gender, decoder: decoder, container: container)
        visitor_type = getValUserDetails(key: .visitor_type, decoder: decoder, container: container)
        email = getValUserDetails(key: .email, decoder: decoder, container: container)
        first_name = getValUserDetails(key: .first_name, decoder: decoder, container: container)
        last_name = getValUserDetails(key: .last_name, decoder: decoder, container: container)
        mobile = getValUserDetails(key: .mobile, decoder: decoder, container: container)
        avatar = getValUserDetails(key: .avatar, decoder: decoder, container: container)



        var tmpComplexUnkeyedContainer = try container.nestedUnkeyedContainer(forKey: .complex)
        var tmpComplex : Complex? = nil
        let tmpComplexContainer = try tmpComplexUnkeyedContainer.nestedContainer(keyedBy: Complex.CodingKeys.self)

        tmpComplex?.company_id = getValComplex(key: .company_id, container: tmpComplexContainer)
        tmpComplex?.unit_id = getValComplex(key: .unit_id, container: tmpComplexContainer)
        tmpComplex?.complex_name = getValComplex(key: .complex_name, container: tmpComplexContainer)
        tmpComplex?.setup_steps = getValComplex(key: .setup_steps, container: tmpComplexContainer)
        tmpComplex?.complex_type = getValComplex(key: .complex_type, container: tmpComplexContainer)
        tmpComplex?.access_type = getValComplex(key: .access_type, container: tmpComplexContainer)
        tmpComplex?.pass_type = getValComplex(key: .pass_type, container: tmpComplexContainer)


        complex = tmpComplex

    }
}
struct ProfileMember: Codable {
    public var units: [String: ProfileUnits]
    let parking: [String]
}
struct ProfileUnits: Codable {
    let unit_type: String
    let building_name: String
    let unit_number: String
    let building_unit_id: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case unit_type
        case building_name
        case unit_number
        case building_unit_id
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        unit_type = getValProfileMember(key: .unit_type, decoder: decoder, container: container)
        building_name = getValProfileMember(key: .building_name, decoder: decoder, container: container)
        unit_number = getValProfileMember(key: .unit_number, decoder: decoder, container: container)
        building_unit_id = getValProfileMember(key: .building_unit_id, decoder: decoder, container: container)
    }
}
struct Subscribed_Applications: Codable {
    let app_id: String
    let app_name: String
    let app_version: String
    let logo: String
    let end_point: String
    let logo_small: String
    let logo_medium: String
    let logo_large: String
    let logo_xsmall: String
}
struct Complex: Codable {
    var company_id: String
    var unit_id: String
    var complex_name: String
    var setup_steps: String
    var complex_type: String
    var access_type: String
    var pass_type: String
    //let complex_events: [String]



    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case company_id
        case unit_id
        case complex_name
        case setup_steps
        case complex_type
        case access_type
        case pass_type
        //case complex_events
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        company_id = getValComplex(key: .company_id, container: container)
        unit_id = getValComplex(key: .unit_id, container: container)
        complex_name = getValComplex(key: .complex_name, container: container)
        setup_steps = getValComplex(key: .setup_steps, container: container)
        complex_type = getValComplex(key: .complex_type, container: container)
        access_type = getValComplex(key: .access_type, container: container)
        pass_type = getValComplex(key: .pass_type, container: container)
        //complex_events = getValComplex(key: .complex_events, container: container)
    }
}
```

This is the actual Response which I am trying to parse :

```
{
  "app": {
    "version": "v1",
    "name": "CHSONE Vizlog",
    "time": "2019-02-07 05:31:08"
  },
  "status_code": 200,
  "data": {
    "metadata": {
      "total": 64899,
      "per_page": 10,
      "current_page": 1,
      "last_page": 6490,
      "from": 1,
      "to": 10
    },
    "results": [
      {
        "log_id": 64899,
        "fk_visitor_id": 65103,
        "fk_building_unit_id": 97,
        "company_id": 7,
        "pass_serial_no": null,
        "card_no": null,
        "number_of_people": 1,
        "purpose_of_visit": "Meeting",
        "in_gate": "Lobby",
        "in_time": "2019-02-06 12:24:31",
        "out_time": null,
        "out_gate": null,
        "in_vehicle_no": null,
        "out_vehicle_no": null,
        "in_vehicle_color": null,
        "out_vehicle_color": null,
        "is_handed_over": 0,
        "access_type": "card",
        "created_at": "2019-02-06 12:24:31",
        "updated_at": "2019-02-06 12:24:31",
        "created_by": 151,
        "updated_by": null,
        "visitors": {
          "visitor_id": 65103,
          "visitor_company_name": null,
          "designation": null,
          "industry": null,
          "used_promotional_channel": null,
          "interested_in": null,
          "platform": "android",
          "iso_code": "IN",
          "dial_code": "91",
          "company_id": 7,
          "first_name": "praduman",
          "last_name": null,
          "gender": "M",
          "mobile": "9080706050",
          "email": null,
          "image_path": null,
          "visitor_type": "guest",
          "coming_from": "vashi",
          "image_large": null,
          "image_medium": null,
          "image_small": null
        },
        "unit": {
          "building_unit_id": 97,
          "fk_building_id": 1,
          "unit_number": "1905",
          "floor_no": "19",
          "building": {
            "building_id": 1,
            "building_name": "CyberOne"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "log_id": 64898,
        "fk_visitor_id": 65054,
        "fk_building_unit_id": 97,
        "company_id": 7,
        "pass_serial_no": null,
        "card_no": null,
        "number_of_people": 1,
        "purpose_of_visit": "Meeting",
        "in_gate": "Lobby",
        "in_time": "2019-02-06 12:19:06",
        "out_time": null,
        "out_gate": null,
        "in_vehicle_no": null,
        "out_vehicle_no": null,
        "in_vehicle_color": null,
        "out_vehicle_color": null,
        "is_handed_over": 0,
        "access_type": "card",
        "created_at": "2019-02-06 12:19:06",
        "updated_at": "2019-02-06 12:19:06",
        "created_by": 151,
        "updated_by": null,
        "visitors": {
          "visitor_id": 65054,
          "visitor_company_name": null,
          "designation": null,
          "industry": null,
          "used_promotional_channel": null,
          "interested_in": null,
          "platform": null,
          "iso_code": "IN",
          "dial_code": "91",
          "company_id": 7,
          "first_name": "Amit",
          "last_name": "Dhawale",
          "gender": "M",
          "mobile": "8055954796",
          "email": null,
          "image_path": "http://test.prosimvizlog.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/7/visitor/visitor_65054.jpg",
          "visitor_type": "guest",
          "coming_from": "sanpada",
          "image_large": "http://test.prosimvizlog.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/7/visitor/visitor_65054_large.jpg",
          "image_medium": "http://test.prosimvizlog.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/7/visitor/visitor_65054_medium.jpg",
          "image_small": "http://test.prosimvizlog.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/7/visitor/visitor_65054_small.jpg"
        },
        "unit": {
          "building_unit_id": 97,
          "fk_building_id": 1,
          "unit_number": "1905",
          "floor_no": "19",
          "building": {
            "building_id": 1,
            "building_name": "CyberOne"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "log_id": 64897,
        "fk_visitor_id": 57222,
        "fk_building_unit_id": 24,
        "company_id": 7,
        "pass_serial_no": null,
        "card_no": null,
        "number_of_people": 1,
        "purpose_of_visit": "Meeting",
        "in_gate": "Lobby",
        "in_time": "2019-02-06 12:08:08",
        "out_time": null,
        "out_gate": null,
        "in_vehicle_no": null,
        "out_vehicle_no": null,
        "in_vehicle_color": null,
        "out_vehicle_color": null,
        "is_handed_over": 0,
        "access_type": "card",
        "created_at": "2019-02-06 12:08:08",
        "updated_at": "2019-02-06 12:08:08",
        "created_by": 151,
        "updated_by": null,
        "visitors": {
          "visitor_id": 57222,
          "visitor_company_name": null,
          "designation": null,
          "industry": null,
          "used_promotional_channel": null,
          "interested_in": null,
          "platform": null,
          "iso_code": "IN",
          "dial_code": "91",
          "company_id": 7,
          "first_name": "Praduman",
          "last_name": "Patil",
          "gender": "M",
          "mobile": "9420256819",
          "email": null,
          "image_path": null,
          "visitor_type": "guest",
          "coming_from": "Future Scape interview",
          "image_large": null,
          "image_medium": null,
          "image_small": null
        },
        "unit": {
          "building_unit_id": 24,
          "fk_building_id": 1,
          "unit_number": "1001",
          "floor_no": "10",
          "building": {
            "building_id": 1,
            "building_name": "CyberOne"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "log_id": 64896,
        "fk_visitor_id": 65054,
        "fk_building_unit_id": 96,
        "company_id": 7,
        "pass_serial_no": null,
        "card_no": null,
        "number_of_people": 1,
        "purpose_of_visit": "Meeting",
        "in_gate": "Lobby",
        "in_time": "2019-01-31 12:34:18",
        "out_time": "2019-01-31 12:40:30",
        "out_gate": "Lobby",
        "in_vehicle_no": null,
        "out_vehicle_no": null,
        "in_vehicle_color": null,
        "out_vehicle_color": null,
        "is_handed_over": 1,
        "access_type": "card",
        "created_at": "2019-01-31 12:34:18",
        "updated_at": "2019-01-31 12:40:30",
        "created_by": 152,
        "updated_by": 151,
        "visitors": {
          "visitor_id": 65054,
          "visitor_company_name": null,
          "designation": null,
          "industry": null,
          "used_promotional_channel": null,
          "interested_in": null,
          "platform": null,
          "iso_code": "IN",
          "dial_code": "91",
          "company_id": 7,
          "first_name": "Amit",
          "last_name": "Dhawale",
          "gender": "M",
          "mobile": "8055954796",
          "email": null,
          "image_path": "http://test.prosimvizlog.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/7/visitor/visitor_65054.jpg",
          "visitor_type": "guest",
          "coming_from": "sanpada",
          "image_large": "http://test.prosimvizlog.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/7/visitor/visitor_65054_large.jpg",
          "image_medium": "http://test.prosimvizlog.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/7/visitor/visitor_65054_medium.jpg",
          "image_small": "http://test.prosimvizlog.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/7/visitor/visitor_65054_small.jpg"
        },
        "unit": {
          "building_unit_id": 96,
          "fk_building_id": 1,
          "unit_number": "1904",
          "floor_no": "19",
          "building": {
            "building_id": 1,
            "building_name": "CyberOne"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "log_id": 64895,
        "fk_visitor_id": 65054,
        "fk_building_unit_id": 96,
        "company_id": 7,
        "pass_serial_no": null,
        "card_no": null,
        "number_of_people": 1,
        "purpose_of_visit": "Meeting",
        "in_gate": "Lobby",
        "in_time": "2019-01-31 11:35:09",
        "out_time": null,
        "out_gate": null,
        "in_vehicle_no": null,
        "out_vehicle_no": null,
        "in_vehicle_color": null,
        "out_vehicle_color": null,
        "is_handed_over": 0,
        "access_type": "card",
        "created_at": "2019-01-31 11:35:09",
        "updated_at": "2019-01-31 11:35:09",
        "created_by": 151,
        "updated_by": null,
        "visitors": {
          "visitor_id": 65054,
          "visitor_company_name": null,
          "designation": null,
          "industry": null,
          "used_promotional_channel": null,
          "interested_in": null,
          "platform": null,
          "iso_code": "IN",
          "dial_code": "91",
          "company_id": 7,
          "first_name": "Amit",
          "last_name": "Dhawale",
          "gender": "M",
          "mobile": "8055954796",
          "email": null,
          "image_path": "http://test.prosimvizlog.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/7/visitor/visitor_65054.jpg",
          "visitor_type": "guest",
          "coming_from": "sanpada",
          "image_large": "http://test.prosimvizlog.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/7/visitor/visitor_65054_large.jpg",
          "image_medium": "http://test.prosimvizlog.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/7/visitor/visitor_65054_medium.jpg",
          "image_small": "http://test.prosimvizlog.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/7/visitor/visitor_65054_small.jpg"
        },
        "unit": {
          "building_unit_id": 96,
          "fk_building_id": 1,
          "unit_number": "1904",
          "floor_no": "19",
          "building": {
            "building_id": 1,
            "building_name": "CyberOne"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "log_id": 64894,
        "fk_visitor_id": 65102,
        "fk_building_unit_id": 97,
        "company_id": 7,
        "pass_serial_no": null,
        "card_no": null,
        "number_of_people": 1,
        "purpose_of_visit": "Meeting",
        "in_gate": "Lobby",
        "in_time": "2019-01-28 14:01:24",
        "out_time": null,
        "out_gate": null,
        "in_vehicle_no": null,
        "out_vehicle_no": null,
        "in_vehicle_color": null,
        "out_vehicle_color": null,
        "is_handed_over": 0,
        "access_type": "card",
        "created_at": "2019-01-28 14:01:24",
        "updated_at": "2019-01-28 14:01:24",
        "created_by": 151,
        "updated_by": null,
        "visitors": {
          "visitor_id": 65102,
          "visitor_company_name": null,
          "designation": null,
          "industry": null,
          "used_promotional_channel": null,
          "interested_in": null,
          "platform": "android",
          "iso_code": "IN",
          "dial_code": "91",
          "company_id": 7,
          "first_name": "hzhd",
          "last_name": null,
          "gender": "M",
          "mobile": "8055678855",
          "email": null,
          "image_path": null,
          "visitor_type": "guest",
          "coming_from": "vashi",
          "image_large": null,
          "image_medium": null,
          "image_small": null
        },
        "unit": {
          "building_unit_id": 97,
          "fk_building_id": 1,
          "unit_number": "1905",
          "floor_no": "19",
          "building": {
            "building_id": 1,
            "building_name": "CyberOne"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "log_id": 64893,
        "fk_visitor_id": 65101,
        "fk_building_unit_id": 96,
        "company_id": 7,
        "pass_serial_no": null,
        "card_no": null,
        "number_of_people": 1,
        "purpose_of_visit": "Meeting",
        "in_gate": "Lobby",
        "in_time": "2019-01-28 14:00:40",
        "out_time": null,
        "out_gate": null,
        "in_vehicle_no": null,
        "out_vehicle_no": null,
        "in_vehicle_color": null,
        "out_vehicle_color": null,
        "is_handed_over": 0,
        "access_type": "card",
        "created_at": "2019-01-28 14:00:40",
        "updated_at": "2019-01-28 14:00:40",
        "created_by": 151,
        "updated_by": null,
        "visitors": {
          "visitor_id": 65101,
          "visitor_company_name": null,
          "designation": null,
          "industry": null,
          "used_promotional_channel": null,
          "interested_in": null,
          "platform": "android",
          "iso_code": "IN",
          "dial_code": "91",
          "company_id": 7,
          "first_name": "test",
          "last_name": "sync",
          "gender": "M",
          "mobile": "8056799285",
          "email": null,
          "image_path": null,
          "visitor_type": "guest",
          "coming_from": "vashi",
          "image_large": null,
          "image_medium": null,
          "image_small": null
        },
        "unit": {
          "building_unit_id": 96,
          "fk_building_id": 1,
          "unit_number": "1904",
          "floor_no": "19",
          "building": {
            "building_id": 1,
            "building_name": "CyberOne"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "log_id": 64892,
        "fk_visitor_id": 47,
        "fk_building_unit_id": 97,
        "company_id": 7,
        "pass_serial_no": null,
        "card_no": null,
        "number_of_people": 1,
        "purpose_of_visit": "Meeting",
        "in_gate": "Lobby",
        "in_time": "2019-01-28 13:47:42",
        "out_time": null,
        "out_gate": null,
        "in_vehicle_no": null,
        "out_vehicle_no": null,
        "in_vehicle_color": null,
        "out_vehicle_color": null,
        "is_handed_over": 0,
        "access_type": "card",
        "created_at": "2019-01-28 13:47:42",
        "updated_at": "2019-01-28 13:47:42",
        "created_by": 151,
        "updated_by": null,
        "visitors": {
          "visitor_id": 47,
          "visitor_company_name": null,
          "designation": null,
          "industry": null,
          "used_promotional_channel": null,
          "interested_in": null,
          "platform": null,
          "iso_code": "IN",
          "dial_code": "91",
          "company_id": 7,
          "first_name": "KOTESHWAR",
          "last_name": "DEVELOPERS",
          "gender": "",
          "mobile": "9819328361",
          "email": "krishnaenterprises400@gmail.com",
          "image_path": "http://test.prosimvizlog.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/7/visitor/visitor_47.jpg",
          "visitor_type": "member",
          "coming_from": null,
          "image_large": "http://test.prosimvizlog.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/7/visitor/visitor_47_large.jpg",
          "image_medium": "http://test.prosimvizlog.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/7/visitor/visitor_47_medium.jpg",
          "image_small": "http://test.prosimvizlog.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/7/visitor/visitor_47_small.jpg"
        },
        "unit": {
          "building_unit_id": 97,
          "fk_building_id": 1,
          "unit_number": "1905",
          "floor_no": "19",
          "building": {
            "building_id": 1,
            "building_name": "CyberOne"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "log_id": 64891,
        "fk_visitor_id": 65100,
        "fk_building_unit_id": 96,
        "company_id": 7,
        "pass_serial_no": null,
        "card_no": "V013",
        "number_of_people": 1,
        "purpose_of_visit": "Meeting",
        "in_gate": "Lobby",
        "in_time": "2019-01-22 05:00:43",
        "out_time": null,
        "out_gate": null,
        "in_vehicle_no": null,
        "out_vehicle_no": null,
        "in_vehicle_color": null,
        "out_vehicle_color": null,
        "is_handed_over": 0,
        "access_type": "card",
        "created_at": "2019-01-22 05:00:43",
        "updated_at": "2019-01-22 05:00:45",
        "created_by": 151,
        "updated_by": null,
        "visitors": {
          "visitor_id": 65100,
          "visitor_company_name": null,
          "designation": null,
          "industry": null,
          "used_promotional_channel": null,
          "interested_in": null,
          "platform": "android",
          "iso_code": "IN",
          "dial_code": "91",
          "company_id": 7,
          "first_name": "test",
          "last_name": null,
          "gender": "M",
          "mobile": "8097679764",
          "email": null,
          "image_path": null,
          "visitor_type": "guest",
          "coming_from": "vashi",
          "image_large": null,
          "image_medium": null,
          "image_small": null
        },
        "unit": {
          "building_unit_id": 96,
          "fk_building_id": 1,
          "unit_number": "1904",
          "floor_no": "19",
          "building": {
            "building_id": 1,
            "building_name": "CyberOne"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "log_id": 64890,
        "fk_visitor_id": 65099,
        "fk_building_unit_id": 96,
        "company_id": 7,
        "pass_serial_no": null,
        "card_no": null,
        "number_of_people": 1,
        "purpose_of_visit": "nnxnx",
        "in_gate": "Lobby",
        "in_time": "2019-01-21 13:20:07",
        "out_time": null,
        "out_gate": null,
        "in_vehicle_no": null,
        "out_vehicle_no": null,
        "in_vehicle_color": null,
        "out_vehicle_color": null,
        "is_handed_over": 0,
        "access_type": "card",
        "created_at": "2019-01-21 13:20:07",
        "updated_at": "2019-01-21 13:20:07",
        "created_by": 151,
        "updated_by": null,
        "visitors": {
          "visitor_id": 65099,
          "visitor_company_name": null,
          "designation": null,
          "industry": null,
          "used_promotional_channel": null,
          "interested_in": null,
          "platform": "android",
          "iso_code": "IN",
          "dial_code": "91",
          "company_id": 7,
          "first_name": "jznznz",
          "last_name": null,
          "gender": "M",
          "mobile": "9767967797",
          "email": null,
          "image_path": null,
          "visitor_type": "guest",
          "coming_from": "hzbzs",
          "image_large": null,
          "image_medium": null,
          "image_small": null
        },
        "unit": {
          "building_unit_id": 96,
          "fk_building_id": 1,
          "unit_number": "1904",
          "floor_no": "19",
          "building": {
            "building_id": 1,
            "building_name": "CyberOne"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

It returns with the error :

**Error info: typeMismatch(Swift.Array, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "data", intValue: nil), CodingKeys(stringValue: "users", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil))**

Below is the exact line where it causes the error :

```
var tmpComplexUnkeyedContainer = try container.nestedUnkeyedContainer(forKey: .complex)
```

Can someone suggest me reason.
Thank you.

Comment: Post the line also where you are decoding it. Error itself is clear that you are trying to parse array instead of dictionary. Remove from [].self in your decoding line.

Comment: https://app.quicktype.io?share=7q1acDpT0qKKqmrtjK8o

Comment: I have edited my question pls check

Comment: You don't need `CodingKeys` and custom `init`s. Just decode `Data` using `JSONDecoder`. Also you can rename properties of your models using *camelCase* and then you can set decoder's `keyDecodingStrategy` to `covertFromSnakeCase` (`property_name` --> `propertyName`)

Comment: I am writing the init methods because I don't know the data type of object and I am converting the value to string every time in init method

Comment: Your response and your structures will not match at all! You should review your structures.

Answer (score 0):

Codable structures created by you are not parsable from your given response.
Please try below structure.

```
// To parse the JSON, add this file to your project and do:

//   var respData = try? newJSONDecoder().decode(RespData.self, from: jsonData)

import Foundation

class RespData: Codable {
var app: App?
var statusCode: Int?
var data: DataClass?

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case app = "app"
    case statusCode = "status_code"
    case data = "data"
}

init(app: App?, statusCode: Int?, data: DataClass?) {
    self.app = app
    self.statusCode = statusCode
    self.data = data
}
}

class App: Codable {
var version: String?
var name: String?
var time: String?

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case version = "version"
    case name = "name"
    case time = "time"
}

init(version: String?, name: String?, time: String?) {
    self.version = version
    self.name = name
    self.time = time
}
}

class DataClass: Codable {
var metadata: Metadata?
var results: [Result]?

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case metadata = "metadata"
    case results = "results"
}

init(metadata: Metadata?, results: [Result]?) {
    self.metadata = metadata
    self.results = results
}
}

class Metadata: Codable {
var total: Int?
var perPage: Int?
var currentPage: Int?
var lastPage: Int?
var from: Int?
var to: Int?

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case total = "total"
    case perPage = "per_page"
    case currentPage = "current_page"
    case lastPage = "last_page"
    case from = "from"
    case to = "to"
}

init(total: Int?, perPage: Int?, currentPage: Int?, lastPage: Int?, from: Int?, to: Int?) {
    self.total = total
    self.perPage = perPage
    self.currentPage = currentPage
    self.lastPage = lastPage
    self.from = from
    self.to = to
}
}

class Result: Codable {
var logID: Int?
var fkVisitorID: Int?
var fkBuildingUnitID: Int?
var companyID: Int?
var passSerialNo: JSONNull?
var cardNo: String?
var numberOfPeople: Int?
var purposeOfVisit: PurposeOfVisit?
var inGate: Gate?
var inTime: String?
var outTime: String?
var outGate: Gate?
var inVehicleNo: JSONNull?
var outVehicleNo: JSONNull?
var inVehicleColor: JSONNull?
var outVehicleColor: JSONNull?
var isHandedOver: Int?
var accessType: AccessType?
var createdAt: String?
var updatedAt: String?
var createdBy: Int?
var updatedBy: Int?
var visitors: Visitors?
var unit: Unit?

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case logID = "log_id"
    case fkVisitorID = "fk_visitor_id"
    case fkBuildingUnitID = "fk_building_unit_id"
    case companyID = "company_id"
    case passSerialNo = "pass_serial_no"
    case cardNo = "card_no"
    case numberOfPeople = "number_of_people"
    case purposeOfVisit = "purpose_of_visit"
    case inGate = "in_gate"
    case inTime = "in_time"
    case outTime = "out_time"
    case outGate = "out_gate"
    case inVehicleNo = "in_vehicle_no"
    case outVehicleNo = "out_vehicle_no"
    case inVehicleColor = "in_vehicle_color"
    case outVehicleColor = "out_vehicle_color"
    case isHandedOver = "is_handed_over"
    case accessType = "access_type"
    case createdAt = "created_at"
    case updatedAt = "updated_at"
    case createdBy = "created_by"
    case updatedBy = "updated_by"
    case visitors = "visitors"
    case unit = "unit"
}

init(logID: Int?, fkVisitorID: Int?, fkBuildingUnitID: Int?, companyID: Int?, passSerialNo: JSONNull?, cardNo: String?, numberOfPeople: Int?, purposeOfVisit: PurposeOfVisit?, inGate: Gate?, inTime: String?, outTime: String?, outGate: Gate?, inVehicleNo: JSONNull?, outVehicleNo: JSONNull?, inVehicleColor: JSONNull?, outVehicleColor: JSONNull?, isHandedOver: Int?, accessType: AccessType?, createdAt: String?, updatedAt: String?, createdBy: Int?, updatedBy: Int?, visitors: Visitors?, unit: Unit?) {
    self.logID = logID
    self.fkVisitorID = fkVisitorID
    self.fkBuildingUnitID = fkBuildingUnitID
    self.companyID = companyID
    self.passSerialNo = passSerialNo
    self.cardNo = cardNo
    self.numberOfPeople = numberOfPeople
    self.purposeOfVisit = purposeOfVisit
    self.inGate = inGate
    self.inTime = inTime
    self.outTime = outTime
    self.outGate = outGate
    self.inVehicleNo = inVehicleNo
    self.outVehicleNo = outVehicleNo
    self.inVehicleColor = inVehicleColor
    self.outVehicleColor = outVehicleColor
    self.isHandedOver = isHandedOver
    self.accessType = accessType
    self.createdAt = createdAt
    self.updatedAt = updatedAt
    self.createdBy = createdBy
    self.updatedBy = updatedBy
    self.visitors = visitors
    self.unit = unit
}
}

enum AccessType: String, Codable {
case card = "card"
}

enum Gate: String, Codable {
case lobby = "Lobby"
}

enum PurposeOfVisit: String, Codable {
case meeting = "Meeting"
case nnxnx = "nnxnx"
}

class Unit: Codable {
var buildingUnitID: Int?
var fkBuildingID: Int?
var unitNumber: String?
var floorNo: String?
var building: Building?

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case buildingUnitID = "building_unit_id"
    case fkBuildingID = "fk_building_id"
    case unitNumber = "unit_number"
    case floorNo = "floor_no"
    case building = "building"
}

init(buildingUnitID: Int?, fkBuildingID: Int?, unitNumber: String?, floorNo: String?, building: Building?) {
    self.buildingUnitID = buildingUnitID
    self.fkBuildingID = fkBuildingID
    self.unitNumber = unitNumber
    self.floorNo = floorNo
    self.building = building
}
}

class Building: Codable {
var buildingID: Int?
var buildingName: BuildingName?

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case buildingID = "building_id"
    case buildingName = "building_name"
}

init(buildingID: Int?, buildingName: BuildingName?) {
    self.buildingID = buildingID
    self.buildingName = buildingName
}
}

enum BuildingName: String, Codable {
case cyberOne = "CyberOne"
}

class Visitors: Codable {
var visitorID: Int?
var visitorCompanyName: JSONNull?
var designation: JSONNull?
var industry: JSONNull?
var usedPromotionalChannel: JSONNull?
var interestedIn: JSONNull?
var platform: String?
var isoCode: ISOCode?
var dialCode: String?
var companyID: Int?
var firstName: String?
var lastName: String?
var gender: Gender?
var mobile: String?
var email: String?
var imagePath: String?
var visitorType: VisitorType?
var comingFrom: String?
var imageLarge: String?
var imageMedium: String?
var imageSmall: String?

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case visitorID = "visitor_id"
    case visitorCompanyName = "visitor_company_name"
    case designation = "designation"
    case industry = "industry"
    case usedPromotionalChannel = "used_promotional_channel"
    case interestedIn = "interested_in"
    case platform = "platform"
    case isoCode = "iso_code"
    case dialCode = "dial_code"
    case companyID = "company_id"
    case firstName = "first_name"
    case lastName = "last_name"
    case gender = "gender"
    case mobile = "mobile"
    case email = "email"
    case imagePath = "image_path"
    case visitorType = "visitor_type"
    case comingFrom = "coming_from"
    case imageLarge = "image_large"
    case imageMedium = "image_medium"
    case imageSmall = "image_small"
}

init(visitorID: Int?, visitorCompanyName: JSONNull?, designation: JSONNull?, industry: JSONNull?, usedPromotionalChannel: JSONNull?, interestedIn: JSONNull?, platform: String?, isoCode: ISOCode?, dialCode: String?, companyID: Int?, firstName: String?, lastName: String?, gender: Gender?, mobile: String?, email: String?, imagePath: String?, visitorType: VisitorType?, comingFrom: String?, imageLarge: String?, imageMedium: String?, imageSmall: String?) {
    self.visitorID = visitorID
    self.visitorCompanyName = visitorCompanyName
    self.designation = designation
    self.industry = industry
    self.usedPromotionalChannel = usedPromotionalChannel
    self.interestedIn = interestedIn
    self.platform = platform
    self.isoCode = isoCode
    self.dialCode = dialCode
    self.companyID = companyID
    self.firstName = firstName
    self.lastName = lastName
    self.gender = gender
    self.mobile = mobile
    self.email = email
    self.imagePath = imagePath
    self.visitorType = visitorType
    self.comingFrom = comingFrom
    self.imageLarge = imageLarge
    self.imageMedium = imageMedium
    self.imageSmall = imageSmall
}
}

enum Gender: String, Codable {
case empty = ""
case m = "M"
}

enum ISOCode: String, Codable {
case isoCodeIN = "IN"
}

enum VisitorType: String, Codable {
case guest = "guest"
case member = "member"
}

 // MARK: Encode/decode helpers

class JSONNull: Codable, Hashable {

public static func == (lhs: JSONNull, rhs: JSONNull) -> Bool {
    return true
}

public var hashValue: Int {
    return 0
}

public init() {}

public required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    var container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
    if !container.decodeNil() {
        throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(JSONNull.self, DecodingError.Context(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Wrong type for JSONNull"))
    }
}

public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
    try container.encodeNil()
}
}
```